# Insert a dash before the last three characters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need to be able to add a dash before the last three characters in a text field using either javascript or php. For example, the user enters 1dsb3rs and the input changes to 1dsb-3rs. It doesn't matter if the user sees the change (javascript) or if it happens server-side (PHP) I just need the change to happen.

I have already tried this javascript code, but I can't get it to work:

```
 $("#rid").html(function(i,v){
  return v.replace( /^([\w]{4})/, "$1-" );
```

Here is my textbox code:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="rid" placeholder="Enter ID" size="15px" maxlength="10" name="rid" required value="<?php echo $rid; ?>">
```

Comment: what is your question and what attempts have you made to resolve it? It is incumbent on you to show these attempts and not just expect people to write code for your needs

Comment: You want it when the user is filling the input field or on submission?

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry. I didn't quite know the format of asking questions on this site. I am new. I have edited my question if that helps any.

Comment: cool...  your doing better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this server-side (assuming data is POST-ed):

```
if (isset($_POST['rid']))
{
    $value = $_POST['rid'];
    if (strstr($value, '-') === false)//if no dash is in the $value string
        $value = substr($value, 0, -3).'-'.substr($value, -3);//get string minus last 3 chars, add dash, then add last 3 chars
}
```

Or client-side using JavaScript (using, for example the change event)

```
document.querySelector('#rid').addEventListener('change', function()
{
    if (this.value > 3)
        this.value = this.value.replace(/(.{3}$)/, '-$1');
}, false);
```

This pattern replaces the last 3 chars with a dash, followed by those very same last 3 chars. [See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x5zGJ/)

Comment: Is there a way to execute your server side code ONLY if $_POST['rid'] doesn't already contain a dash?

Comment: @blazerunner44: Updated the answer... BTW: [RTM](http://www.php.net/strstr). Every function there is has a manual page on php.net. Spend some time looking through the string functions, and figure it out for yourself SO isn't a free code-generator

Comment: I'd say if ```(strlen($value) > 3 && strstr($value, '-') === false)```

Answer (score 1):

```
String.prototype.splice = function( idx, rem, s ) {
    return (this.slice(0,idx) + s + this.slice(idx + Math.abs(rem)));
};

String.prototype.addDash = function () {
    return this.splice( -3, 0, '-' );
};

document.getElementById('myinput').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\-/gi, '');
    if (this.value.length >= 4) {
        this.value = this.value.addDash();
    }
});
```

Working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/seancannon/2xLFy/2/

Comment: there is a problem here, looks like the character `-` is an invalid char, and user is not allowed to type that char.

Comment: Ya it'll strip the dashes and add one 4 spaces before the end of the string. That's the extent of my Sunday morning code brain :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `html()` method on a form control. You need to use `val()`.

Try:

```
$("#rid").val(function(i,v){
  v.replace( /^([\w]{4})/, "$1-" );    

});
```

**[jQuery val() API docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/)**

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you in javascript.

```
var addDash = function(str){
    var chars = str.split("");
    chars.splice(chars.length-3,0,'-');
    return chars.join('')
}
```

call this function with string.

```
addDash('string');
```

Output

```
str-ing
```